# Methods to diagnose why an application works for local user account but fails on a network user account?

Tags: debugging, active-directory, centos

I have setup a CentOS 6.5 machine that is attached to my company's domain. The OS is configured to allow Active Directory authentication so we do not have to have separate usernames and passwords to login into it.

The application ANSYS Mechanical works fine when I launch it while logged in with a local (non AD) account. However, when its launched while logged in with my AD account, it reports:

```
Script Error
Line: 25959
Char: 2
Error: Object required
Code: 800a01a8
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
Script: var pg=pm.PreferencesCategories.Item("CATNAME_DesignModeler").PreferencesGroups;
```

My question is, what tools and methods should I be using to help me diagnose this odd issue?

The aim would be to either fix a possible bad setting at my end or to communicate to the software vendor my problem. The software vendor would not help since the application does work with regular local user account, however, if I have more specific info I could approach the developers.

I feel that there is some configuration setting that is causing this.

Comment: The application is a .NET application that uses some combination of native code and the rest through mono and MainWin to make it work on linux.

Comment: Maybe something in the environments of the two users is different?

Comment: Investigated the difference in environment as suggested by X Tan and found none.

Comment: Could it be an issue with limits? How can I use strace to confirm/eliminate this possibility?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a difference in the environment that is established during login for each of the users, I would start by doing the following.

- Login as localuser, type `env > /usr/tmp/localuser.env`
- login as aduser, type `env > /usr/tmp/aduser.env`

And then look at the differences, and make them the same. Maybe solution is to add missing settings into aduser's login profile.

Aid's to check environments.

```
cd /user/tmp
sort localuser.env >localuser_sorted.env
sort aduser.env >aduser_sorted.env

diff localuser_sorted.env aduser_sorted.env >usersenv.dif
less userenv.dif
```

Comment: There was no differences in the environment (using your suggestion), with the exception of the actual user-names and home path.

Comment: So no difference except, "user name and home path", well there's a difference, what's the difference between home paths ? `ls -la` the two home paths ? What groups do the respective users belong. )ps, the more info you provide the netter we can diagnose and waste less time on comments). Please update your original quetsion with further information, you can [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/117243/edit) your question. tks